# use a variable defined in a function outside the function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have this function here.

```
def choose_file():
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('xodr Files', '*.xodr')])
    if file:
        res = "selected:", file
    else:
        res = "file not selected"
    return(res)
```

I have this button to open the dialog and choose a file

```
e3=Button (scalF, text='Wählen Sie ein Dokument',font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight',12),command=choose_file, bg='blue')
e3.pack(side='top')
```

after choosing a file and closing the dialog I want to display the value of the variable defined res in the `choose_file()` in the label below

```
chosenFile = Label(scalF,text="I want to write here",font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 10))
chosenFile.pack(side='top')
```

can you explain how to read the variable `res`from the global scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*`tk.StringVar`* to hold the strings variables](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/control-variables.html).

```
file_result = tk.StringVar()

def choose_file():
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('xodr Files', '*.xodr')])
    if file:
        res = "selected: {0}".format(file.name)
    else:
        res = "file not selected"
    file_result.set(res)
```

Then this variable(`file_result`) can be passed to `Label`s [*`textvariable`* argument](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_widget.htm#M-textvariable)(Whose value will be used in place of the text).

```
chosenFile = Label(scalF, font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 10), textvariable=file_result)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks!! @Abdul Niyas P M
just one question: i don't have my function ```choose_file()``` inside the root = Tk() so i moved ```file_result = tk.StringVar()``` under root = Tk(). is that the best thing to do or should i move the function under the root = Tk() as well?

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways i can recommend is :
add `global res` to the 1st line of ur function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable in the global scope by declaring it using the `global` keyword.

```
def choose_file():
    global res
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('xodr Files', '*.xodr')])
    if file:
        res = "selected:", file
    else:
        res = "file not selected"
    return(res)
```

If you wanna explore more, you can learn about [namespaces](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) in python

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class:

```py
class File():
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = None

        e3=Button (scalF, text='Wählen Sie ein Dokument', font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight',12), command=self.choose_file, bg='blue')
        e3.pack(side='top')

    def choose_file(self):
        # Your implementation but updating self.res, without return

    def get_res(self):
        return self.res
```